# How do I prove that these two integrals are equal? (Analysis 1)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How can I go about proving that
$$ \int_{0}^{x}f(u)(x-u)du=\int_{0}^{x}\left ( \int_{0}^{u}f(t)dt \right )du $$
I know that I'm supposed to use the fact that if $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}xf(t)dt$ then $  F'(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt+xf(x) $ , but I have no idea how to work with the presence of the 2nd integral on the right hand side.

Comment: What do you get if you integrate the left hand side by parts ?

Comment: We haven't done by parts integration yet. I know I'm supposed to differentiate both sides, but I don't know how to take the derivative of the right hand expression.

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate the left hand side ?

Comment: I believe so, yes

Comment: Then the right hand side is not much different.

Comment: Right, but what I'm having trouble with is that I have no idea how to do it when there are multiple integrals like that. It's probably really simple, but I just don't know how to apply chain rule to it.

Comment: which is important is the term inside the outer integrand (which contains $x$). You can just call $H(t)= \int_0^tf(u)du$ and when you derive the right hand side, you find that the derivative is equal to $H(x)= \int_0^xf(u)du$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\int_0^xf(u)(x-u)du$ and $G(x)=\int_0^x\int_0^uf(t)dt\,du$.

$F(x)=x\int_0^xf(u)du-\int_0^xuf(u)du$. This implies that $F'(x)=\int_0^xf(u)du+xf(x)-xf(x)=\int_0^xf(u)du$.

$G'(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$.

This implies that $F$ and $G$ have the same derivative, since $F(0)=G(0)$. We conclude that $F(x)=G(x)$.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Can you just quickly run me through how you got G'(x)?

Answer (score 0):

Integrating by parts gives
$$\begin{align}
 \int_{0}^{x}f(u)(x-u)du&=\left.(x-u)\times\int_{0}^{u}f(t)dt\right|_{u=0}^{u=x}-\int_{0}^{x}(x-u)^{'}_{u}\left ( \int_{0}^{u}f(t)dt \right )du \\\\
&=0+\int_{0}^{x}\left ( \int_{0}^{u}f(t)dt \right )du 
\end{align}$$ as announced.